# lstlistings works strangely

Tags: listings, sourcecode, java

I have some Java source code and want to display it in LaTex:

```
\lstset{language=Java}
\begin{lstlisting}
    IntentFileter intentfilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentfilter.addAction("com.anguanjia.action.download.START_DOWNLOAD");
    intentfilter.addAction("com.anguanjia.action.download.DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS");
    g = new blm(this, null);
    m.registerReceiver(g, intentfilter);
\end{lstlisting}
```

But the output is indeed ugly:
[image]

Did I do something wrong or this is what it ought to be?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This may serve to be a starting point towards procrastination and beautification:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstset{language=Java,
    basicstyle=\footnotesize\ttfamily,
    commentstyle=\ttfamily\itshape\color{gray},
    stringstyle=\ttfamily,
    showstringspaces=false,
    breaklines=true,
    frameround=ffff,
    frame=single,
    rulecolor=\color{black},
    tabsize=1,
    keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries,
    columns=fullflexible,
    morekeywords={public, class}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{lstlisting}
    IntentFileter intentfilter = new IntentFilter();
    intentfilter.addAction("com.anguanjia.action.download.START_DOWNLOAD");
    intentfilter.addAction("com.anguanjia.action.download.DOWNLOAD_SUCCESS");
    g = new blm(this, null);
    m.registerReceiver(g, intentfilter);
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can customise further using  the directives inside `\lstset`. For details, refer to `listings` manual. For extreme beautification, you may use `tcolobox` with its `listings only` option. Search for `tcblisting` in `tcolorbox` documentation.

Comment: Your enthusiasm did impress me. And I'm still wondering why there isn't a more convenient way to have a better format of source code, at least a monospace font for example.

Comment: @Elderry Not choosing a monospace font by default was a precise choice made by the package author, who was apparently fond of listings in normal type. I usually add also `columns=fullflexible` to avoid spaced letters.

Comment: Instead of `keywordstyle=\color{red}\bf,` you could put `keywordstyle=\color{red}\bfseries,` to get bold monospaced letters if available (unless you DID want that output).

Comment: @egreg Thanks. I left many things assuming that the list may grow. I added it now. :)

Comment: @Manuel That was a nice suggestion and I did bad copy pasting. Corrected. :)